# `phonegap run ios` -> `create: Command failed with exit code ENOENT`

Tags: ios, cordova

With PhoneGap, running `phonegap run ios` (as admin or not) on Windows 8 in my app's directory gives the following output:

```
[phonegap] detecting iOS SDK environment...
[phonegap] using the local environment
[phonegap] adding the iOS platform...
{ [Error: C:\Users\Me\.cordova\lib\ios\cordova\3.5.0\bin\create: Command failed with exit code ENOENT] code: 'ENOENT' }
  [error] C:\Users\Me\.cordova\lib\ios\cordova\3.5.0\bin\create: Command failed with exit code ENOENT
```

I'm trying to use it with the phonegap ios app.  What's wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't build iOS apps on Windows.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/guide_platforms_ios_index.md.html#iOS%20Platform%20Guide

Comment: First response on seeing "C:\", yup that's windows.

Comment: Yes, turns out I wanted `phonegap serve` instead.  The flow of the installation tutorial is confusing if you don't know all of what phonegap does - http://phonegap.com/install/ suggests `phonegap run android` after install and I needed ios so I made that guess and got the unhelpful error message.  Thanks.